# .draggable revert back to original position after link has been clicke

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-draggable, revert

Struggling here, I'm Using .draggable on a div which works fine but I also need a link so that once a user has dragged the div anywhere on the page they can "Reset" it back to it's original position.

```
$(function() {
    if (! /iphone|ipad|ipod|android|blackberry/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase())) {
        $( "#race_charts_container" ).draggable({ revert: false, cancel: "#graphs_content"});
    }
        });


$("#btnReset").click(function() {
    $("#race_charts_container").animate({
           left: '+=50px',
           top: '+=50px'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look this **demo** :
http://jsfiddle.net/M8Ehe/1/

Just set top and left to 0.

**Code** :

```
$(function() {
    if (! /iphone|ipad|ipod|android|blackberry/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase())) {
        $( "#race_charts_container" ).draggable({ revert: false, cancel: "#graphs_content"});
    }
        });


$("#btnReset").click(function() {
    $("#race_charts_container").animate({left:0,top:0});
});
```